Proof of variant Sperner's Theorem for divisibility posets
I'm trying to determine the size of the maximal antichain in the poset of divisors of $N$ where the partial order is divisibility. Looking at the prime factorization of $N=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_d^{e_d}$ one can see that this is equivalent to finding the maximal antichain of a $d$-dimensional box of coordinates $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ where $x_i\in [e_i]$ and one element is $\leq$ another iff each of its coordinates are $\leq$ the respective coordinate in the other element.
It's "obvious" that the maximum antichain can be found by considering level sets i.e. subsets of the poset whose elements all have the same sum of their coordinates. Each of these level sets are antichains and I'm convinced that the biggest such level set will (nonuniquely) occur when we take the set of all elements whose coordinates sum to $\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^d e_i\right\rfloor$. I saw a proof that polynomials whose coefficients are symmetric, nonnegative, and unimodal are closed under multiplication which proves this.
However, this claim is only obvious in the sense that Sperner's theorem is obvious for the case that $e_1=e_2=\cdots=e_d=2$. Which from looking at the proofs of it is not very much. I've looked online at various proofs of Sperner's theorem and I can't figure out how to extend them to this more generalized poset. The proofs I found seem to use some property of permutations or symmetric chain decompositions which don't seem to make sense in the general case. It doesn't help that there isn't actually a nice closed form for the size of the maximum level set

Nevermind, I found a proof in this paper https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/4373475/597494.pdf
It basically explicitly constructs the chain decomposition by inducting on the number of distinct primes dividing $N$ by creating these sort of $L$ shapes.
